# react-infinite-scroll-component with multiple columns

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, infinite-scroll, react-infinite-scroll-component

I'm creating an app that shows a gallery of images (varying heights). I implemented the infinite scroll with 4 columns (masonry effect). But whenever I scroll down and the fetchMore function is called, the new images that are added to the gallery div shuffle the earlier images.

I followed a couple tutorials but the elements (images) seem to be all the same height and width so maybe my masonry effect is creating the shuffle?
[screenshot of old images "shuffling" due to new images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZ25u.jpg)

Here's my code:

```
const AppContext = createContext();

const AppContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [allPhotos, setAllPhotos] = useState([]);
  const [pageNum, setPage] = useState(1);

  const clientID = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_IMG_ACCESS_KEY;

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const fetchData = () => {
    axios({
      method: "GET",
      url: `https://api.unsplash.com/topics/film/photos?`,
      params: { page: pageNum, client_id: clientID, count: 10 },
    }).then((res) => {
      console.log(pageNum);
      setAllPhotos([...allPhotos, ...res.data]);
      setPage(pageNum + 1);
    });
  };

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={{ allPhotos, fetchData }}>
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
};

export { AppContextProvider, AppContext };
```

in my home page

```
import { useContext, useState } from "react";
import { AppContext } from "../components/AppContext";
import Gallery from "@/components/Gallery";
import InfiniteScroll from "react-infinite-scroll-component";
import Loader from "@/components/Loader";

export default function Home() {
  const { allPhotos, fetchData } = useContext(AppContext);

  return (
    <div className={`flex flex-col items-center p-10`}>
      <h1>Gallery Wall</h1>
      <InfiniteScroll
        dataLength={allPhotos.length} // might have to place in reducer because num is constantly changing
        next={fetchData}
        hasMore={true}
        loader={<Loader />}
        endMessage={<h4>fin.</h4>}
      >
        <Gallery images={allPhotos} />
      </InfiniteScroll>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In my Gallery component, I'm using tailwind css to make the columns (columns-4) and in my Image component, I just have a mb-4 (margin-bottom: 4px).

```
const Gallery = ({ images }) => {
  return (
    <div className={`columns-4`}>
      {images.map((img) => (
        <Image key={img.id} src={img.urls.raw} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

The result I want is a smoother loading of the new images as you scroll down but not sure if that's achievable.

Comment: What library are you using for the masonry?

Comment: I'm using tailwind css for the masonry effect so no library per se. It's in my gallery component so let me update this question.